# How do I send messages to Telegram bot using Pyrogram?

Tags: python-3.x, telegram, python-telegram-bot, pyrogram

I've built a rather neat LLM-based Telegram bot using python-telegram-bot. I tried to figure out how to do E2E testing and found that people use Pyrogram for these purposes. However, when I try to send a message with Pyrogram to the bot using bot id, I get 'ID not found: XXXXXXXXXX' (XXXXXXXXXX replaces my bot id).

I do manage to send messages to myself using my id (they end up in "Saved" messages folder), which means this can't be Pyrogram not working/not authenticated correctly etc.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is to create a Telegram group, add your Bot to the group (adding admin permissions to it) and then send a message to the group. The bot will react to a specific command like '/start' or will react to a group message.

Comment: Thanks! I did try that before and get the same error (ID not found), though I use the specific chat id for that. One question - any idea why my chat id in case of this particular group is negative?

Comment: Can you provide the code snippet to check on my side?

Comment: Sure - here is what I do: <code> pyro_bot = Client("quiz_bot_tester", api_id=config_utils.get_config().PYRO_TELEGRAM_API_ID,
                      api_hash=config_utils.get_config().PYRO_TELEGRAM_API_HASH, workdir=".") </code>
    await pyro_bot.start()
    await pyro_bot.send_message(int(config_utils.get_config().TELEGRAM_GROUP_ID), "/start")
    await pyro_bot.stop()

Comment: Groups and channels have negative IDs and regular users have positive IDs.

Comment: Thank you, Andrii! Re my TS question, maybe better posed should have been - how should I test my bot? I saw some pretty clunky examples of unit testing in python-telegram-bot github, and of course stumbled upon Pyrogram/Telethon recommendations for E2E, but any other more elegant recommended ways?